# use multiple general perpose queries or one specific query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, database-design

I have a Web-App that control selling and buying of merchandise as well as stock and prices...

it is built with AngularJs, PHP and MySQL(PDO).

My Model has many General perpose query functions such as:

- getShops()
- getShopInfo(shopId)
- GetItems(shopId)
- GetSuppliers()

and many more...

now, i develop a `Dashboard Page`, to show statistics and Top-Level vision on things, containing f.e:

- Number of active items
- Number of Sold items + total sum
- Current Debt to suppliers

and many more aggregations on the data.

My question is what option of the two:

**Should i use many basic queries in my model, and aggregate the data Client-Side...**
will this be bit more maintainable?

OR

**Should i create a Specific Query to get exactly what data this dashboard needs.**
probably performance will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should without a doubt create a specific query to get exactly what data your dashboard needs. In fact, you should create a view for it so that the actual `select` statement is plain simple. It has several advantages:

- Aggregation is what databases are good at: indexes are used (if you design it well), and results are cached for all clients to benefit from, resulting in a performance that can hardly be beaten;
- The `SQL` language is quite suitable for formulating aggregations, certainly when you compare it to client-side `JavaScript`;
- It will help you in debugging. Without running the web app, you can run the `select` directly on your database to verify the result, and so better isolate any problems;
- If you create a database `view`, you can even decide to one day change the internal definition of the `view` without having to touch your Web App code;
- The volume of data transfered between server and client is kept minimal: only the needed data is transferred. This can be important for users connecting over mobile networks.